# Will any ldlinux.c32 work for creating a live ISO?

Tags: live-usb, iso

I'm trying to make a Live ISO for USB. I'm following a [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) to help me do this, and one of the steps says to:
`cp /usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/ldlinux.c32 image/isolinux/`, but I don't have `/usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/ldlinux.c32` on my system. I've tried `find -iname ldlinux.c32` but nothing is returned. I've installed `isolinux` and `syslinux`, but that hasn't helped.

I searched Google for `ldlinux.c32  intitle:"index of" -inurl:(jsp|pl|php|html|aspx|htm|cf|shtml) -inurl:(listen77|mp3raid|mp3toss|mp3drug|index_of|wallywashis)`, and found ldlinux.c32 in a few open directories. Will any one I pick, work? I'm concerned that this is not even close to best practice, but I can't figure out how else to get ldlinux.c32. The syslinux website assumes you have it, from what I read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Library_modules

> All Syslinux variants need an additional ldlinux module
>
> Since version 5.00, when a SYSLINUX or EXTLINUX installer is used, the relevant boot sector will be modified and two files will be added to the "installation directory": the ldlinux.sys boot loader file, and an auxiliary ldlinux.c32 file. Note that these two files are not necessary so as to execute the installers; they are already embedded in the installers themselves.
>
> For other Syslinux variants (PXELINUX, ISOLINUX) booting BIOS firmware, the second file, ldlinux.c32, needs to be manually added, just as the boot loader. Both files shall match the same version. For example, before building a new ISOLINUX image, two files are now needed: the isolinux.bin boot loader file, and the same auxiliary ldlinux.c32 file.

**ISOLINUX/PXELINUX**

Download syslinux from [kernel.org](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/)

The files should be present in the downloaded package.

```
$ find syslinux-6.00 -name "ldlinux.*[0-9]*"
syslinux-6.00/bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.c32
syslinux-6.00/efi32/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.e32
syslinux-6.00/efi64/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.e64    
$ find syslinux-6.00 -name "isolinux.bin"
syslinux-6.00/bios/core/isolinux.bin
```

**SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX**

You only need your `syslinux` or `extlinux` file. The file `ldlinux.c32` is contained in these files and is automatically installed when you run "syslinux -f -i" or "extlinux -i" (or an installer script) to make your drive bootable.

See the Syslinux manual: [Creating a Bootable Disk - Linux](https://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#Linux)